# github saving containing directories

Tags: git, github

When I push my project to github, the the repository also saves the the directories containing the project.

For example if I have a project in the directory `webdevstuff` on my desktop, git will save the repository as

```
desktop/webdevstuff/project
```

instead of just the `project` directory

Sorry for the dumb question, I'm new to this.

Comment: Git doesn't store directories at all, it just stores files by path name. If the path name of the file is `desktop/webdevstuff/project/foo`, Git will have to create directory `desktop/` if necessary (if it does not already exist), then create sub-directory `webdevstuff/` within that if necessary, and so on, until it has a place to create file `foo`. If you don't want it to create the file under the name `desktop/webdevstuff/project/foo`, don't *save* it under that name in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm still somewhat confused by this. 

How should I save my files then? If I just want git to *just* save my project folder, not the entire directory leading up to it, what should I do? should I only put projects on my root directory to prevent this?

Also, why is git arbitrarily saving desktop/webdevstuff, and not going all the way up to my root directory?

Comment: Git starts wherever you put the `.git` repository. In general, if you're creating a new repository, you do it with: `cd <place you want the repository to live>; mkdir <project-name>; cd <project-name>; git init`. If you're cloning some existing repository, you do it with: `cd <place you want the repository to live>; git clone <url>; cd <repository just created by cloning>`. Files then have names relative to that repository.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want your directory structure on GitHub side to only reflect project, you should make sure to create your local repo in project/ (`project/.git`) locally.

If you have a `desktop/.git` folder, that means you all desktop is one Git repo, which is generally not recommended.